# .htaccess several rewrites and one by default

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi there I have a problem with my htaccess file, I want to redirect the calls to different files and if the call does not match redirect by default to index.php

this is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^callOne(|/.*)$ callOnephp?q=$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^callTwo(|/.*)$ callTwo.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

So, if the call is made to /callOne the file named callOne.php will respond but if not the call will be answered by index.php. As well if the call is made to callTwo the file named callTwo.php will respond, if not the index.php will respond by default.

Currently the calls are always answered by index.php. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with call made to `/AnythingElse` ?

Comment: Some optional tasks, I know that I can route the calls through index.php but this is a requirement of the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^call(One|Two)$ call$1.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```